# C - Disable possibilities user already used

Tags: c, algorithm

I couldn't find this anywhere...

I am making a project at my university - very simple. I have some questions/possibilities user can make... after using it, I want to disable it and never show so user can proceed in "while" loop to another.

Example:

```
while (something == true)
{
printf("Your possibilities are:\n 1 - Use a hammer\n 2 - Use a pipe\n 3 - Use a chair\n");

choice = getchar();

switch (choice)
{
  case '1':
    someCode();
    break;
  case '2':
    someCode();
    break;
  case '3':
    someCode();
    break;
}}
```

This is of course an example. Problem is, that after user used a hammer, some code will happen and then - I want only 2 possibilities: "pipe" and "chair". So next chance will be only "two-way" switch. In my code I have 6 possibilities and making bool for every choice and combine all six bools in if-else and then writting for each possibility a switch is unthinkable.

Is there any solution for this? Propably there is needed a bool variable for every possibility (if that is used) but I need to define that switch in some way.

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, a 'harder' problem is easier to solve. Instead of having three hard-coded options, how would you write the program if you needed to store everything in some sort of data structure? (e.g. if the options were stored in file, and you didn't know ahead of time how many there were)

Comment: have an array of questions and an array of 'already asked' bools

Comment: Well, good idea, but what about that switch? For example if user uses a pipe (number two) next time it will disappear and chair will be number two. That is what I struggle with.

Comment: @Stepan You're actually better off *not* changing the numbers. The reason is that users plan ahead. For example, the user will look at the list of three items and decide to choose 2, 3 and then 1, because they want the pipe, chair, and hammer. And they'll be confused and annoyed that 3 doesn't work after choosing the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of items and a parallel set of flags to keep track of what has been used.
Some pseudo code follows

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const char *item[] =
    { "a hammer", "a pipe", "a chair", "an awl", "an hour", 0 };
#define ITEM_N (sizeof item/sizeof item[0] - 1)

// return EOF on end-of-file/input error
// return 0 when no choices
// return 0 when non-numeric data entered
// return 0 when 0 or too high a value entered
// return 0 when a used value is selected
int Choice(bool *Used) {
  int choice = -1;
  puts("Your possibilities are:");
  for (int i = 0; item[i]; i++) {
    if (test_if_value_i_has_not_been_used) {
      print_prompt;
      choice = 0;
    }
  }
  if (choice < 0) {
    puts(" None");
    return 0;
  }
  char buf[50];
  read_user_input_into(buf);  // return EOF if no input
  if (!an_int_was_entered(&choice) ) return 0;
  if (choice_in_range) return 0;
  if (was_choice_used_before) return 0;
  Used[choice - 1] = true;
  return choice;
}

int main(void) {
  bool Used[ITEM_N] = { 0 };  // clear all flags
  while (Choice(Used))
    ;
  return 0;
}
```